# Elements from map function in React is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to render any elements returned from a function in rendering

```
this.state.globalConfirmedCases.isLoading 
                        ? 
                    <Loading/> 
                        : 
                    this.generateCount(this.state.globalConfirmedCases)
generateCount = ()=> {
        this.state.globalConfirmedCases.data.map((item, index)=>{
            console.log(typeof(item.confirmed.value))
            console.log(this.state.globalConfirmedCases.data)
            return (
                <CountUp
                    key={index}
                    end={item.confirmed.value}
                />
            )
        })
    }
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I am wondering if its race condition. meaning your state might not have data when it renders? do you see output in console.log(this.state.globalConfirmedCases.data)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `generateCount()` function does not return anything, just `undefined`.

Try instead as the following in order to return what `.map()` creates:

```
generateCount = () => this.state.globalConfirmedCases.data.map((item, index) => 
   <CountUp key={index} end={item.confirmed.value} />
)
```

See an example for difference:

```js
const array = [1,2,3];

const example1 = () => {
   array.map(e => e);
}

const example2 = () => array.map(e => e);
    
console.log(example1());
console.log(example2());
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @JithinZacharia Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You should share more detailed code here for better understanding the issue. Anyhow, what I think is you are not returning the function. 
Write return in front of this keyword like:

```
generateCount = ()=> {
        return this.state.globalConfirmedCases.data.map((item, index)=>{
            console.log(typeof(item.confirmed.value))
            console.log(this.state.globalConfirmedCases.data)
            return (
                <CountUp
                    key={index}
                    end={item.confirmed.value}
                />
            )
        })
    }
```